# Custom written migration does not run

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to write my own migration script. My migration class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace Foo.Migrations
{
    public class FooMigration : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
          string script ="<some long script>"
            migrationBuilder.Sql(script);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run Update-Database, nothing happens...

Comment: Did you try a simple script to see where the problem really is?

Comment: @Haytam actually the script isn't that long... and i have tested it and it works but the migration doesn't get called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the DbContext which the migration belongs to and the identifier of your migration by applying attributes to your migration class as shown below:

```
[DbContext(typeof(MyDbContext))]
[Migration("MyCustomMigration")]
public class FooMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        string script = "<some long script>";
        migrationBuilder.Sql(script);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dunno. I just looked at some auto-generated migrations emitted by the `dotnet ef migrations add` command and it became obvious that these attributes are required.